# RegEx to extract hardcoded strings in HTML

Tags: html, regex, hardcoded

I need some help for extracting hard coded strings out of HTML.

This is a example markup from the template engine that I use

```
[[if:"x";"y"]]
    <p>true part</p>
[[:else]]
    <p>false part</p>
[[:endif]]

[[each:ARRAY;KEY;VALUE]]
    Index :[[KEY]] is :[[VALUE]]

    or if VALUE is an array
    Index :[[KEY]], FOO is :[[VALUE:FOO]]
[[:endeach]]

{$_TEMPLATE['VARS']}

<p><b>I want this</b> and this, {%'AND **THIS NOT**, THIS IS ALREADY TRANSLATED
SINGLE QUOTE MARK IS ESCAPED BY A BACKSLASH \' '}
LINES</p>
```

Currently I use that pattern `/>([^\<\>\n\{\}]+\S*?)+</is` but it work not reliable.

`:[[VAR]]`, `{$_TEMPLATE['VAR']}` and control-blocks(`[[if:"x";"y"]]` etc.) should not be extracted. In case of mixed text (Foo `:[[has]]` bar) should `Foo` and `bar` extracted separately

For the attributes, I using the pattern `/(placeholder|title|alt|value)\=\"([^\"\'=\{\}\[\]]*?)\"/` which is no Problem

I hope you can help me.

**EDIT: Required output from this example:**

```
true part
false part
Index 
is
or if VALUE is an array
Index
, FOO is
I want this
and this
```

Comment: What would you like to extract from this file? -- Supply a sample output please.

Comment: `<p><b>this text</b> {%'THIS NOT,. SINGLE QUOTE MARK IS ESCAPED BY A BACKSLASH \' '} this text also</p>
[[if:"x";"y"]]
    <p>true text</p>
[[:else]]
    <p>false text</p>
[[:endif]]`
I want this as the output
`this text`
` this text also`
`true text`
`false text`

Comment: First what you ask is very unclear. Second, if I even understand what you want, this is not a RegEx task. You might be better of just traversing each line of the file/string and just detecting simpler patterns and in multiple `tests` on simpler pattern, canceling out more complex first versus less complex later. RegEx isn't magic and shouldn't be abused for broader logic; that's when you use code-blocks (like fallback functions).

Comment: Please check if this solves your problem: `(?si)\s*(?:\{\$.*?\}|:?\[\[.*?\]\]\p{P}?|\{\%.*?\}|<.*?>)\s*(*SKIP)(*F)|\b([^:{}<>\[\]\n\r]+)\b`: https://regex101.com/r/tA4kK4/1